# Summarizing a dataset and creating new variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataset that lists individual transactions by country, quarter, division, the transaction type and the value. I would like to sum it up based on the first three variables but create new columns for the other two. The dataset looks like this:

```
Country   Quarter   Division    Type    Value
   A         1        Sales      A        50
   A         2        Sales      A       150
   A         3        Sales      B        20
   A         1        Sales      A       250
   A         2        Sales      B        50
   A         3        Sales      B        50
   A         2      Marketing    A        50
```

Now I would like to aggregate the data to get the number of transactions by type as a new variable. The overall number of transactions grouped by the first three variables is easy:

```
df.groupby(['Country', 'Quarter', 'Division'], as_index=False).agg({'Type':'count', 'Value':'sum'})
```

However, I would like my new dataframe to look as follows:

```
Country   Quarter   Division    Type_A   Type_B     Value_A   Value_B
   A         1        Sales        2        0         300         0
   A         2        Sales        1        1         150        50
   A         3        Sales        0        2           0        70
   A         2      Marketing      1        0          50         0
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify column after `groupby` with tuples in `agg` functions for new columns names with aggregate functions, then reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and last convert `MultiIndex` in columns by `map`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['Country', 'Quarter', 'Division', 'Type'])['Value']
         .agg([('Type','count'), ('Value','sum')])
         .unstack(fill_value=0))
df1.columns = df1.columns.map('_'.join)
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
  Country  Quarter   Division  Type_A  Type_B  Value_A  Value_B
0       A        1      Sales       2       0      300        0
1       A        2  Marketing       1       0       50        0
2       A        2      Sales       1       1      150       50
3       A        3      Sales       0       2        0       70
```